# How to combine jar file and .sql file in one program

Tags: java, mysql, jar

I have code in java, so to use the program I must convert it to a jar file, but my program needs .sql file to run.

I want to give this program to my client. Can I give it just one file/program ?

Not the jar and .sql file, because if I send these two file I need to tell him how to import the .sql file first and connect the database.

All I want is I make a program that includes the jar and .sql file in one program then he can use it when I send it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to give this program to my client. Can I give it just one file/program ?

Yes you can do that.  You start by adding the SQL file to the file tree that you create the JAR from.  (Different build tools have different ways of doing this.  For example, if you are using Maven you add the SQL file to the resources directory and it will be included in the JAR by Maven.)  The file then becomes a "resource" in the JAR file.

Next your application should use the `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/some/path")` to open the resource as a stream.

The final step depends on how you are going to use the SQL.

- You could simply read the resource stream and write it to a file in the customers file system.
- You could use `ProcessBuilder` to exec (say) the "mysql" command and write the resource's standard input.

Comment: with this way, my client don't need to connect the database right ? for example i'm using xampp.. my client don't need to connect it right ? sorry for the spelling

Comment: There is not sufficient information in your question to answer that.  But it seems odd that you want to include an SQL file but your application doesn't connect to the database.  How is the SQL relevant to the application?  What doe is to?

Comment: Im sorry for that.. yes my application connects to the database. My application will do some CRUD Syntax to database, so it will need access the database. Im using Netbeans 8.2 for my application and MySQL(xampp) for my dabatase.